# При оплате не переходит на сайт платежной системы

Tags: php

Устанавливаю платежку. При нажатии на сайте "Оплатить" открывается пустая страница этого же сайта и всё, на сайт платежки не переходит. В чем может быть ошибка?

Параметры:

```
        <?php
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        include('files/functions.php');
        
 
        $link = "https://enot.io/pay?";
        $payment_id = time("utf-8", 'windows-1251', "Пополнение баланса ID " . $UserID);
        $sign = md5($settings['FkShopId'] . ":" . $_GET['amount'] . ":" . $settings['FkSecret'] . ":". $payment_id);

        $options = [

            'm' => $settings[FkShopId],

            'oa' => $_GET['amount'],

            'o' => $payment_id,

            's' => $sign,

            'us_id' => $UserID,
        ];
     
        header("Location: " . $link . http_build_query($options));
```

Форма:

```
<?php
if(!empty($settings['FkShopId']) && !empty($settings['FkSecret'])) {
  ?>
    <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
      <form method="GET" action="fk-check.php">
        <input type="hidden" id="new_amount_kassa" name="amount" value="1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="<?php echo $settings['currency']; ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" disabled id="kassa" class="submit_btn btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round" value="Пополнить">
                    </form>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Вообще-то, по [примеру](https://enot.io/en/knowledge/first-payment) на сайте, запрос на платёж производится не редиректом, а через POST ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая ошибка в строчке формирования `$payment_id`.
Функция time() ничего не принимает - [читайте документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)!
Подозреваю что вы хотели конвертировать строку в другую кодировку и добавить время вначале.

```
$payment_id = time() . mb_convert_encoding("Пополнение баланса ID " . $UserID, "utf-8");
```

Вторая ошибка в строке

```
'm' => $settings['FkShopId'],
```

Ну и на будущее добавьте отображение ошибок для дебага (в начале документа)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
// ... Ваш код
```

Comment: Спасибо, дело сдвинулось, на сайт енота теперь перехожу, но страница выдает ошибку 404, в url стоят нужные параметры.

Comment: Всё, проблема решена)